# Facebook Login using scribe

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, scribe, malformedurlexception

I'm using scribe to get user id, however I get this error:
OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.

I follow this example enhanced with javax filters (to get the parameter code correctly)
https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/FacebookExample.java

I also tried doing things manually and i got the access token which looks somehow like this ( i changed it a bit ) CAAHZCFE7YllgBAAZAenKbvZBrMZAZBkDGgydU2vAekwsM1V0StpZAgHXukEYWIDSpc5ZCXc4LB6suFeaPagcpj2ju6ayvAgrxYttvCQg9i7ZAdcF2ZCvhMNqTddsDUkNq1c1cX47U9KwutS5t6xpbV0cRabaVpgZCZAo4ZCTEtgckFmMajsb3zYWTH9LEfKj3CgcJ39lD2x1yRoXyAds0lKARmHZC

and while asking for user id like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAAHZCFE7YllgBAAZAenKbvZBrMZAZBkDGgydU2vAekwsM1V0StpZAgHXukEYWIDSpc5ZCXc4LB6suFeaPagcsj2ju6aYvYgrxYttvCQg9i7ZAdcF2ZCvhMNqTddsDUkNq1c1cX47U9KwutS5t6xpbV0cRabaVpgZCZAo4ZCTEtgckFmMajsb3zYWTH7LEfKj3CycJ39lD2x1yRoXyAds0lWLRmHZC%20,%20458856e03b909f426ec5d3791f0af466?fields=id,name

I get Malformed access token.
Do you have any suggestions regarding what I am doing wrong?
The URLs are the same, dunno what my mistake is :/

Comment: your token has spaces in it '%20,%20'. Please verify that you have got the correct access token value. To test graph API with oauth, use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: i pasted one of my access tokens in the debugging tool and it showed me my id and name, however i still get oauthexception while doing this:

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAAHZCFE7YllgBAAZAenKbvZBrMZAZBkDGgydU2vAekwsM1V0StpZAgHXukEYWIDSpc5ZCXc
4LB6suFeaPagcpj2ju6aYvYgrxYttvCQg9i7ZAdcF2ZCvhMNqTddsDUkNq1c1cX47U9KputS5t6xpbV0
cRabaVpgABAAo4ZCTEtgckFmMajsb3zYWTH7LEfKj3CycJ39lD2x1yRoXyAds0lWLRmHZC?fields=id,name
(changed the token a bit but only characters to others)

Comment: I don't understand why when i paste my access token to the debugging tool it shows me my credentials, but when i do this through web browser i get the effin error ;(

Comment: ok, SOLVED
the error was that instead of ?fields=id,name
should be &fields=id,name
such a noobie mistake !